# How does SOL accounting work in non-rent-exempt programs?

Tags: program, rent, state

I wonder how does one reason about SOL accounting in [non-rent-exempt](https://docs.solana.com/developing/intro/rent#rent-exempt) Programs?

It seems to me that static analysis of a Program's balance is impossible besides just assuming that it changes on each storage update (and between blocks, too).

For context: my background is in Ethereum, where most state rent proposals (e.g. [EIP-1682](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1682)) have incorporated a separate opcode for the rent balance.

Answer (score 1):

It's thankfully very simple -- programs are required to be rent-exempt by the program loader.

Comment: Can't a Program become non-rent-exempt if there's some custom logic that withdraws a sufficient amount of SOL?

Comment: No, the program loader owns other programs, so only the program loader can withdraw SOL from other programs. And the program loader only does full withdrawals of accounts. And on top of that, *all* new accounts must be rent-exempt.